# How to parse multipart/form-data body with Koa?

Tags: javascript, koa, body-parser

Because I spent some (too much) time figuring out this simple requirement. I am documenting here the way to achieve `multipart/form-data` body parsing with Koa.

In my case, the reason of the confusion was the number of alternatives available out there:

- [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body)
- [koa-better-body](https://github.com/tunnckoCore/koa-better-body)
- [koa-body-parser](https://github.com/thomseddon/koa-body-parser)
- [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser)

And I wanted to find the most minimalist/close to `express/koa/node` way/philosophy of doing things.

So here it is. Below. In accepted answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use [koa-multer](https://github.com/koa-modules/multer) as stated in the official [Koa wiki](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki#body-parsing).

So a simple setup would look like:

```
const koa = require('koa');
const multer = require('koa-multer');

const app = koa();

app.use(multer());

app.use(function *() {
  this.body = this.req.body;
});
```

*A couple of notes*:

- Multer will only parse bodies of requests of type `multipart/form-data`
- **Notice** the use of `this.req.body` instead of Koa's supercharged `this.request` (not sure if this is intentional but this is confusing for sure... I would expect the parsed `body` to be available on `this.request`...)

And sending this HTML form as [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="topsecret" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="area51[lat]" value="37.235065">
  <input type="text" name="area51[lng]" value="-115.811117">
  ...
</form>
```

Would give you access to nested properties as expected:

```
// -> console.log(this.req.body)
{
  "topsecret": 1,
  "area51": {
    "lat": "37.235065",
    "lng": "-115.811117",
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually [asked why](https://github.com/koa-modules/multer/issues/2) parsed body in not available on `this.request`.

Comment: Just a heads up to folks that the currently maintained fork is this [`@koa/multer`](https://github.com/koajs/multer)

Answer (score 14):

For [Koa2](https://github.com/koajs/koa/tree/v2.x), you can use [async-busboy](https://github.com/m4nuC/async-busboy) as other solutions dont support **promises** or **async/await**.

Example from the docs:

```
import asyncBusboy from 'async-busboy';

// Koa 2 middleware
async function(ctx, next) {
  const {files, fields} = await asyncBusboy(ctx.req);

  // Make some validation on the fields before upload to S3
  if ( checkFiles(fields) ) {
    files.map(uploadFilesToS3)
  } else {
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

Comment: Use with autoFields.
    var parts = await asyncBusboy(ctx.req, {
       autoFields: true // saves the fields to parts.field(s)
    });

Answer (score 10):

I have three solutions that works for me:

1. **koa-body**, note it parses `multipart/form-data` only with `multipart: true` option.

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaBody = require('koa-body');
const Router = require('koa-router');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(koaBody({ multipart: true }));

router.post('/', async ctx => {
    const body = ctx.request.body;
    // some code...
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

2. **koa-bodyparser**, parses `multipart/form-data` only with `koa2-formidable` middleware before it.

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');
const formidable = require('koa2-formidable');
const Router = require('koa-router');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

app.use(formidable());
app.use(bodyParser());

router.post('/', async ctx => {
    const body = ctx.request.body;
    // some code...
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

3. **@koa/multer**, note it parses `multipart/form-data` only if installed `multer` package. Also note that `koa-multer` is deprecated, do not use it.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const multer = require('@koa/multer');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();
const upload = multer(); // you can pass options here

app.use(upload.any());

router.post('/', async ctx => {
    const body = ctx.request.body;
    // some code...
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 5):

I went through the same investigation than you and here are other ways to achieve `multipart/form-data` body parsing with Koa.

**co-busboy**:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var parse = require('co-busboy');

const app = koa();

app.use(function* (next) {
  // the body isn't multipart, so busboy can't parse it 
  if (!this.request.is('multipart/*')) return yield next;

  var parts = parse(this),
      part,
      fields = {};
  while (part = yield parts) {
    if (part.length) {
      // arrays are busboy fields 
      console.log('key: ' + part[0]);
      console.log('value: ' + part[1]);

      fields[part[0]] = part[1];
    } else {
      // it's a stream, you can do something like:
      // part.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('some file.txt'));
    }
  }

  this.body = JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2);
})
```

**koa-body**:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var router = require('koa-router');
var koaBody = require('koa-body')({ multipart: true });

const app = koa();

app.use(router(app));

app.post('/', koaBody, function *(next) {
  console.log(this.request.body.fields);

  this.body = JSON.stringify(this.request.body, null, 2);
});
```

In both cases you will have a response like:

```
{
  "topsecret": 1,
  "area51": {
    "lat": "37.235065",
    "lng": "-115.811117",
  }
}
```

But personally, I prefer the way koa-body works. Plus, is compatible with other middleware like [koa-validate](https://github.com/RocksonZeta/koa-validate).

Also, if you specify an upload dir to koa-body, it will save the uploaded file for you:

```
var koaBody = require('koa-body')({
  multipart: true,
  formidable: { uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'tmp') }
});
```

Comment: How do you use async await when using function*(next)? async function*(next) gives 404