# How to upload file using FormData with multer in node js, getting undefined in req.file and { } in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express

How to upload file using FormData with multer in Node.js? I am getting undefined in req.file and { } in req.body.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)">
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        //Take the first selected file
        console.log("files", files);
        fd.append("file", files[0]);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/upload',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
            data: fd

        }).then(function (response) {
        }, function (error) {
        });

    };
```

Here is the server side code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'public' });
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(200)
})


app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {

  console.log("req.file", req.file); //req.file undefined
  console.log("req.body", req.body); //req.body {}

});

app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log("server listening on port 5000 ");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The backend code looks ok, however you need to set the correct content-type on the client-side.

By providing the form-data as its data argument you should not actually have to define the content-type explictily. So you can simply do:

```
$http('http://localhost:5000/upload', fd)
```

If you want to specify the content-type explicitly, you can use:

```
$http('http://localhost:5000/upload', fd, {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: Does the upload work if you use a tool like postman to do the request?

Comment: Yes, its working through postman. But not through browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax for executing the POST request.

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", files[0], "/path/to/file");

var settings = {
  "url": "http://localhost:5000/upload",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to set up a minimalistic server using Koa and lowdb; I am also writing everything on typescript and using the experimental feature to work with modules in (nodejs) koa.

I share firstly my .tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "es6","DOM"
    ] ,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src" ,
    "strict": true ,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",                 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
   
    /* Advanced Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
```

Did manage to set up the server but got in a lot of trouble when I wanted to add on **Multer** and effectively, which library to chose from to handle the incoming data.

on this [**POST**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751203/how-to-parse-multipart-form-data-body-with-koa) there is a good discussion about the different libraries available at the end I chose to use [async-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-busboy) [...] seems to be more up to date, and of course, bring on its own types.

> koa is known to treat everything as middleware, so wrappers on async-await are useful!

```js
import multer from '@koa/multer';
import koaStatic from 'koa-static';
import path from 'path';
import asyncBusboy from 'async-busboy';
import multer from '@koa/multer';
import koaStatic from 'koa-static';
import path from 'path';
import asyncBusboy from 'async-busboy';


const router = new Router();
const app = new Koa();

const corsOpt = {
  origin: /* process.env.CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN ||  */ '*', // this work well to configure origin url in the server
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'], // to works well with web app, OPTIONS is required
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'], // allow json and token in the headers
};
app.use(cors(corsOpt));
app.use(logger());
app.use(koaBody());

app.use(koaStatic(__dirname + './static/uploads'));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + '.jpg');
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.use(upload.any());

app.use(async function (ctx: KoaContext, next: () => any) {
  // ignore non-POSTs
  if ('POST' != ctx.method) return await next();
  const { files, fields } = await asyncBusboy(ctx.req);
  console.log(files);
  let err = await upload
    .single('file')(ctx as any, next)
    .then((res: any) => res)
    .catch((err: any) => err);
  if (err) {
    ctx.body = {
      code: 0,
      msg: err.message,
    };
  } else {
    ctx.body = {
      code: 1,
      data: files,
    };
  }
});

// add a route for uploading multiple files
router.post('/uploader', upload.fields([]), (ctx: KoaContext) => {
  console.log('ctx.request.files', ctx.request.files);
  console.log('ctx.files', ctx);
  console.log('ctx.request.body', ctx.request.body);
  ctx.body = 'done';
});

// REST OF CODE ...

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(4040);
console.log('server running ... http://localhost:4040');
```

I am still learning, or better said decypher all typescript secrets by doing such experiments. Now I do have a conflict as mutler is doing its own form-data (I assumed by reading from others posts) So far it is a solution to get the file from ctx.req.file via async-await, But I do still struggling with the types.

You can check the whole project here [repo](https://github.com/creative-sources/lowdb_server)

Any help on the types will be great.

Hope it helps to further this discussion now with typescript.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.