# problem with simultaneous parsing of body for content type application / xml; charset = utf-8 and multipart in Koa Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, parsing, koa, body-parser

I get webhooks in xml format so tot parse I use 'koa-bodyparser' like this:

```
app.use(
     bodyparser ({
       extendTypes: {
       text: ['application / xml'],
       },
       enableTypes: ['json', 'text'],
       }),
       );
```

Unfortunately, it does not have multipart support, so to add pictures in my routes I have to use 'koa-body' and

```
app.use (
      bodyParser ({
        multipart: true,
        includeUnparsed: true,
      }),
    ) ;.
```

Each of them performs their functions separately, but at the same time they are mutually exclusive and I cannot use them simultaneously. How to do it so that both roles are fulfilled simultaneously? Some other package? Any idea? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem here, I was basically using koa-body works well, but when I need to upload files I got to bring multer, It was not working so I debug a bit and by removing the body parser I got multer to work.

But now I have no parser for JSON. I did used [async-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-busboy) and I am guessing is doing multers job. But got to keep multer to do the file filtering and ext name and such.

So I suggest you check on those lib and also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751203/how-to-parse-multipart-form-data-body-with-koa) was quite useful to understand how is this working. By now I guess you might have found a solution, if so; Do share.

I am working on a very minimal server using koa and lowdb can check [repo](https://github.com/creative-sources/lowdb_server) I guess my problems are also because of types and overloading functions.